# how to dynamically add an image in Javascript while using Flask

Tags: javascript, flask

I was trying to dynamically add an image to a div every time  `SendChatbotMessage()` gets called but javascript adds unnecessary stuff to the jinja block

here's my function code:

```
function SendChatbotMessage(message) {
    const chatElement = document.getElementById('chat');
    if (chatElement) {
      const htmlCode = `
      <div class="question">
      <div class="img">
          <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/icon.png') }}" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="gpt-title">
        ${message}
      </div>
      `;
      chatElement.innerHTML = htmlCode;
    } else {
      console.error("Chat element with ID 'chat' not found!");
    }
  }
```

the GET of the url_for() request should look something like this:

`"GET /static/assets/mic.png HTTP/1.1"`

but javascript adds %20...%20 to the request and it looks like this:

`GET /{{%20url_for('static',%20filename='assets/icon.png')%20}} HTTP/1.1`

how do i prevent javascript from adding this stuff?

I have searched hard on the internet and tried every ai humanly possible, but nothing worked out.

Comment: It seems like you are using a jinja command outside of the environment. Have you moved your JavaScript code to an external file?

Comment: yes it's in an external .js file

Comment: Jinja is executed on the server side in contrast to JavaScipt. Since you use the `url_for()` command outside the environment, it will not be rendered and will appear within the URL. Jinja commands are only valid within template files and the respective endpoint. So you can either move the specific part of your code there or provide a direct path to the icons within the JavaScript code. Unfortunately, I don't have enough insight into your application to give you advice or an example.

Comment: putting a direct path worked for me.